# Access - Network drive/shared-folder only for a program - not for user

Tags: windows, security, share, shared-directory

I have a programm (erp) that needs a network-drive/shared-folder from my windows server.

The problem with this is, I need to implement it as a network drive (internal network) for all client pc.

**The problem:**

If a user e.g. a trainee use the programm, I can setup the correct role for that user that **in the programm** so that the user can only do certain actions (e.g. register new customers,..)

However if he/she wants to get lets say all invoices with customer data he/she can copy it from the network drive/share. Thats uncool.

Is there a possibility to only allow that or a program to access the network drive/share?

The program needs to read and write.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you should create a group for the network share and only allow members of the group to access the network share. Sounds like you are asking if a program can have more permissions than the user? The answer would be No. A program running under a user, has the permissions of the user. The only way I can think of is if you create a server component that runs with permissions to access the network share and then have "the program" interact with the service to do what it needs. You'll still have to lockdown the share permissions from non-authorized users.

Comment: Access control is implemented per user account. You cannot restrict access to anything that is not a user account.